# Interaction of body with an elevator that is accelerating it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

I'm a bit confused with Newton's third law.

If, for example, an elevator has a person inside it and then accelerates, the person inside feels a force up which equals the weight of the person and the force of the elevator. Shouldn't the elevator experience the same force but downwards?

Comment: yes it does....

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't the elevator experience the same force but downwards?

Yes.

On the other hand, if you want to know the effect of the equal and opposite forces on the person and elevator individually, you need to apply Newton's second law $F_{net}=ma$ to the person and elevator individually.

Hope this helps.